# Shop By menu link is not coming in category page mobile view magento 2 is anyone have any idea regarding this?

Tags: magento2

> shop by menu is not coming in category page mobile view magento 2  is anyone have any idea regarding this.

Comment: Please check browser's console for any js errors.

Comment: Make sure that there is no rule for desktop only on the navigation menu.

Comment: I checked in console also there is no error and again we have same other app ie working properly.

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: Yes one error is there in system.log file is critical issue is related that bootstrap.min.css.map is not working some bootstrap.min.css.map related only

Comment: Please share the error

Comment: Please check the answer.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Comment: Yes there was code problem actually we overrides layer navigation module thats why link was not coming.

Comment: Okay please post your issue and solution so which will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The correct permission for the **apache** with `mod_php` for the `pub/static` and `var/` folders. From the [Alan Storm article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_adding_frontend_files_to_your_module)

```
find /path/to/magento2/pub/static -exec chmod 777 '{}' +
find /path/to/magento2/var/ -exec chmod 777 '{}' +
```